# RTL footnotes suddenly switch to LTR

Tags: footnotes, hebrew, reledmac, right-to-left, reledpar

I'm using LuaLaTeX to typeset a Hebrew text with an RTL critical apparatus.
As long as the footnotes are only from lemmata in lines 1 and 2, this works fine.
When footnotes for line 3 lemmata are added, the double pipe separators (that should go between line 1 and 2 notes, and line 2 and 3 notes) move to the wrong places, and the the line 2 footnotes (on both lines in the apparatus containing a double pipe) become ordered LTR.
The line 1 and line 3 footnotes however are correctly ordered RTL.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Scale=0.9]{David}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xparafootsep{ $\parallel$ }
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline
\Xsymlinenum{|}
\Xnotenumfont{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
  \pstart
\edtext{אאא}{\Afootnote{אאאאאאא 7}} \edtext{בבב}{\Afootnote{בבבבבבב 7}}:

\edtext{גגג}{\Afootnote{גגגגג 8}} \edtext{דדד}{\Afootnote{דדדדד 8}} \edtext{ההה}{\Afootnote{ההההה 8}} \edtext{חחח}{\Afootnote{חחחחח 8}} \edtext{טטט}{\Afootnote{טטטטט 8}} \edtext{כככ}{\Afootnote{כככככ 8}}:

\edtext{צצצ}{\Afootnote{צצצצצ 9}} \edtext{קקק}{\Afootnote{קקקקק 9}}:     

  \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

The only thing that seems to resolve the problem is to only have lemmata from the first two lines, but this is unfeasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the math made `$\parallel$`. Maths is LTR and this seems to stuff up the direction of things in the footnote.

My suggestion is to use the Unicode ∥ symbol from the Latin Modern Math font instead, like this:

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newfontfamily\lmmath{Latin Modern Math}
\newunicodechar{∥}{{\lmmath ∥}}

\Xparafootsep{ ∥ }
```

## MWE

(Sorry, slightly different font.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=footnotes]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default,main]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[%
  Scale=0.9,
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Medium,
  ItalicFont = *-MediumItalic,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic]{DavidCLM}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newfontfamily\lmmath{Latin Modern Math}
\newunicodechar{∥}{{\lmmath ∥}}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}
\Xparafootsep{ ∥ }
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline
\Xsymlinenum{|}
\Xnotenumfont{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\beginnumbering
  \pstart
\edtext{אאא}{\Afootnote{אאאאאאא 7}} \edtext{בבב}{\Afootnote{בבבבבבב 7}}:

\edtext{גגג}{\Afootnote{גגגגג 8}} \edtext{דדד}{\Afootnote{דדדדד 8}} \edtext{ההה}{\Afootnote{ההההה 8}} \edtext{חחח}{\Afootnote{חחחחח 8}} \edtext{טטט}{\Afootnote{טטטטט 8}} \edtext{כככ}{\Afootnote{כככככ 8}}:

\edtext{צצצ}{\Afootnote{צצצצצ 9}} \edtext{קקק}{\Afootnote{קקקקק 9}}:     

  \pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]